# SQLite database not accepting more than 1000 rows?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am writing an android app. I am parsing lines from a txt file and inserting data from each line into an SQLite database. But the insertion process stops at exactly 1000 entries. There are more that 3000 entries, but the insertion process stops at 1000. What is going wrong?

Edit: Here is the code:

```
try{
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("feedtitlesandaddresses.txt");
            InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(iz);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "<");
            String firstNumber="";
            String strfinal="";
              **//code which gives values to strfinal and firstNumber excluded
              values.put(KEY_NAME, firstNumber); // Contact Name
              values.put(KEY_PH_NO,strfinal); // Contact Phone

              // Inserting Row

              db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);}




   }catch(Exception e){Log.d("yeah error is"+e,"twitch12");}
```

Comment: How does android's readLine() method handle a line in the txt file that consists only of carriage return or linefeed? Is that line = "" or null?

Comment: @tim I assume you are talking about end of file. It is null and not "".

Comment: I meant end-of-line.  Is there any possibility the text file contains a "blank" line (nothing but the end-of-line character) which is being resolved to NULL by the readLine() method?

Comment: @tim No, there is no problem with the line, I removed 2 lines from above that line and ran the app, Now the 1000th entry is the one which is 2 lines below the problematic line, so the line has no problem in it..

Comment: just in case, if you are checking out data using some tool like `sqlite_database_browser`, make sure you observe the next button to see more data available on next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is going wrong?

It's strange i guess. Problem may be related to both(problem with file or db).

Did you think about `TRANSACTION`? It may solve your problem. I recently worked with db and normal inserted 100 000 rows(but in transaction for sure) because without transaction your operation will take a lot of time.

So as my recommendation wrap your code into transaction and reading and writing will take much less time and it should solve problem.

**Pseudocode:**

```
try {
   db.begiTransaction();
   ...
   // your work with file and inserting
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   ...
}
finally {
   if (db.inTransaction()) {
      db.endTransaction();
   }
}
```

### Update:

Look at 1000. line in file and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried what you suggested, but still it stops at 1000 entries..

Comment: It is just like others. I don't think it is a problem with the file, as the line is just like all others and 1000 is too round a number.., it must be something with sqlite or database..

Comment: @user2213396 uhm and any error? try to first read from file, save values into list and then perform inserting.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- Go to SQLiteStudio
- Select Tools > Open Configuration dialog > Data browsing
- In Data browsing you will have `Number of data rows per page`, now
  choose the size as you wish.

I have same problem as yours, and I changed the number 1000 to 2000 and it worked like a charm. Hope it will work for you.